# JQueryUI not working with multiple buttons that use the same ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So these are my buttons

```
<button name="btnSubmit" value="refreshPreview">Refresh Preview</button>
<button name="btnSubmit" value="saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
```

I use the same ID because in PHP I just see if $_POST['btnSubmit'] = 'refreshPreview' or 'saveChanges' which I feel is a valid use.

This JQuery does not affect either button. How can I correct this, is there a way to select all buttons with the same ID?

```
$( "#btnSubmit" ).button();
```

Thanks

Comment: name is different than id, try adding the id attribute to your controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you would actually need is:

```
$('button[name="btnSubmit"]').button();
```

Or select using a class like the other answers which is probably the better thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a fundamental mistake. The jQuery # [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) refers to the ID, and not to the Name.

Please rewrite as:

```
<button class="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="refreshPreview">Refresh Preview</button>
<button class="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
```

And the JS as:

```
$( ".btnSubmit" ).button();
```

Beware that the ID always must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your buttons have an id:

```
<button name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="my-button" />
```

Name isn't the same as the id. You shouldn't use the same id for two elements. Use a class name instead:

```
$( ".my-button" ).button();
```

Comment: "You shouldn't use the same id for two elements." - it should be "You MUSTN'T use the same id for two elements." :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# = id
```

but you have set the name not the id!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ID for multiple elements in HTML. Then it wouldn't be an id. In PHP you are actually referring the name of the HTML element and not the ID so you don't have to worry about conflicts. Give unique IDs and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique across your HTML document. What you're using is a name attribute that can be accessed by:

```
$('[name="btnSubmit"]').button();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#btnSubmit" ).button();
```

This selects the `btnSubmit` ID. There is no such element in your markup. What you have are two buttons with this **name**. If you had `id = "btnSubmit"` in those buttons, it might work.